# how to update AlarmManager in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am new to Android Development.
Presently I am developing the To-Do events app.

In this app I am setting a notification using Pending Intent. In this I am using the **AlarmManager**. After setting alarm the notification occurs on exact time.

Note: In Pending Intent I used Unique Id.(Here unique id means Getting row record id from database).

Here my problem is,
when I am updating **AlarmManager** the notification is not coming in exact time. It comes after when I update the **AlarmManager**.

My Updating Code is:

```
private void updateAlarm(int year,int month,int date,int hour,int minute,int second,String event_id,String e_desc) 
{
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)               this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month-1, date, hour, minute, second);
        long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();         // notification time

        String event_desc = e_desc;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderContent.class);
        intent.putExtra("EventDesc", e_desc);
        int alarm_id = Integer.valueOf(event_id);

        //alarm_id is the Id of PendingIntent which is already created.

        PendingIntent pendingInt = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alarm_id , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, when, pendingInt);
}
```

Is my procedure correct for updating **AlarmManager**?

Comment: Yes correct.. what  exactly happening?

Comment: thank you for reply@Ankit. Here when i create an event at first time the AlarmManager works correct.After first time alerted i am again going to update the AlarmManager by using above stated funtion. This time when i update the event the next second the notificaion is occurs with out taking latest updation time of AlarmManager.